# Adding a scene information after a plot_ly object has been created

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

I have plotly 3D scatterplot objects I have saved as .rda files and would like to load into r markdown. My problem is that I would like to use the subplot function to have four 3D plots in the one screen (dimension 2 x 2). The example dataset provided on the Plotly website shows    how this can be achieved, but the problem is I cannot redo my plotly images (i.e. define the scene name for each plotly object. Is there a way to define the scene of an existing plotly object (the example below obviously doesn't work but I was wondering if there would be something equivalent),

```
names(plotly_object$x$layoutAttrs$`1feXXXXXXXXX`$scene <- 'scene1'
```

Below is the example solution provided on the `plotly` website. My problem is that I didn't define `scene='scene3'`, although to be honest I never would as these objects are created throughout a pretty long workflow and I am never sure at the time of creation which plots will be included in my final `r-markdown` document.

```
library(plotly)

# custom grid style
axx <- list(
  gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
  zerolinecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
  showbackground=TRUE,
  backgroundcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)'
)

# individual plots
fig1 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, scene='scene1') 
fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_surface(showscale=FALSE)

fig2 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, scene='scene2') 
fig2 <- fig2 %>% add_surface(showscale=FALSE)

fig3 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, scene='scene3') 
fig3 <- fig3 %>% add_surface(showscale=FALSE)

fig4 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, scene='scene4') 
fig4 <- fig4 %>% add_surface(showscale=FALSE)

# subplot and define scene
fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4) 
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "3D Subplots",
         scene = list(domain=list(x=c(0,0.5),y=c(0.5,1)),
                      xaxis=axx, yaxis=axx, zaxis=axx,
                      aspectmode='cube'),
         scene2 = list(domain=list(x=c(0.5,1),y=c(0.5,1)),
                       xaxis=axx, yaxis=axx, zaxis=axx,
                       aspectmode='cube'),
         scene3 = list(domain=list(x=c(0,0.5),y=c(0,0.5)),
                       xaxis=axx, yaxis=axx, zaxis=axx,
                       aspectmode='cube'),
         scene4 = list(domain=list(x=c(0.5,1),y=c(0,0.5)),
                       xaxis=axx, yaxis=axx, zaxis=axx,
                       aspectmode='cube'))

fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to assign this to `layoutAttr`. Even if you set the scenes originally, there would still be issues with setting the scene. This has more to do with an error in the R version of Plotly.

I've broken this down in detail because you didn't share your data or plots. Initially, I've got two plots. One with scenes; one without scenes. At the end of this answer, I show you how to rearrange the scene.

If you created scenes when you created each plot, when you created the subplot, it created the named scenes...kind of. (This is a `plotly` issue!)

I used the example you provided with and without the layout function in the original plot call. Consider the following plots. Note that for the first plot, I've made it upside down.

```
fig1 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano * -1, scene = 'scene1') %>%  # upside down
  add_surface(showscale = FALSE)

fig2 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, scene = 'scene2') %>% 
  add_surface(showscale = FALSE)

fig3 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, scene = 'scene3') %>%
  add_surface(showscale = FALSE)

fig4 <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano, scene = 'scene4') %>% 
  add_surface(showscale = FALSE)

fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4) %>% 
  layout(title = "3D Subplots",
         scene = list(domain = list(x = c(0,0.5),y = c(0.5,1)),
                      xaxis = axx, yaxis = axx, zaxis = axx,
                      aspectmode = 'cube'),
         scene2 = list(domain = list(x = c(0.5,1),y = c(0.5,1)),
                       xaxis = axx, yaxis = axx, zaxis = axx,
                       aspectmode = 'cube'),
         scene3 = list(domain = list(x = c(0,0.5),y = c(0,0.5)),
                       xaxis = axx, yaxis = axx, zaxis = axx,
                       aspectmode = 'cube'),
         scene4 = list(domain = list(x = c(0.5,1),y = c(0,0.5)),
                       xaxis = axx, yaxis = axx, zaxis = axx,
                       aspectmode = 'cube'))

plt <- subplot(fig1, fig2, fig3, fig4) # no layout specified
```

To make sure I have everything, I am going to rebuild both plots.

```
fig <- plotly_build(fig)
plt <- plotly_build(plt)
```

[image]
[image]

You can see that the plot on the right is a hot mess.

If you look at the current layout for each of these plots, these are the attributes `plotly` set.

```
names(fig$x$layout)
#  [1] "NA"         "NA2"        "NA3"        "NA4"        "margin"    
#  [6] "scene"      "hovermode"  "showlegend" "title"      "scene2"    
# [11] "scene3"     "scene4"     

names(plt$x$layout)
# [1] "NA"         "NA2"        "NA3"        "NA4"        "margin"    
# [6] "scene"      "hovermode"  "showlegend"
```

Do you see all of the `NA` names? That's all garbage. That's all on Plotly in R.

Using the scene domains specified in the first plot, I created two vectors. Then I created a function for creating the `scene`.

```
x <- rep(c(0, .5, .5, 1), 2)           # x for 4 position scene
y <- c(.5, 1, rep(c(0, .5), 2), .5, 1) # y for 4 position scene

sn <- function(x, x1, y, y1, axx) { # function for creating a scene
  list(domain = list(x = c(x, x1), y = c(y, y1)),
       xaxis = axx, yaxis = axx, zaxis = axx,
       aspectmode = 'cube')
}
```

Next, I used `map2` to create the scenes for `plt`. This function comes from the `purrr` library. (I usually just call `tidyverse` to cover the gamut... and in case I have the wrong number of 'r's in that library name...)

```
map2(1:4, seq(1, length(x), by = 2),
     function(i, k) {            # i =  1, 2, 3... k = 1, 3, 5...
       if(i == 1) {
         scnName = "scene"                   # create scene names
       } else {
         scnName = paste0("scene", i) # scenes 2 - 4
       }
       if(scnName %in% names(plt$x$layout)) { # if already named in layout
         ind = which(these == scnName, arr.ind = T)
       } else {
         names(plt$x$layout)[i] <<- scnName
       }
       plt$x$layout[[scnName]] <<- sn(x[k], x[k + 1], y[k], y[k + 1], axx)
     })
```

This is what `plt` looks like now.

[image]

If I wanted to rearrange the scene, I could have done it when I created them. However, I can change them now, as well.

For example, if I wanted to up the upside down volcano in the top left spot into the bottom right spot, I can just swap the scenes between 1 and 4.

```
newS = fig$x$layout$scene
fig$x$layout$scene <- fig$x$layout$scene4
fig$x$layout$scene4 <- newS
fig
```

[image]